# Can someone please explain what this LINQ query does?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am having trouble understanding this LINQ query. This is what I think is happening.

```
1. from stat in XpoSession.Query<STUDENT>()
2. where stat.ID_PERSON.DT_BIRTH >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20)
3. && stat.Status.Where(val => val.CD_REASON == Constants.REASON_PLACED).Count() == 0
4. select stat.CD_STATUS.Trim()).ToList().GroupBy(val => val);
```

#1. Data source is `STUDENT` table from database.

#2. Gets all STUDENTS that are less than or equal to 20 years old.

#3. This is the part I don't understand. There is a `STUDENT_STATUS` table which has a `CD_REASON` column so I am assuming that `stat.Status` is really `STUDENT_STATUS.CD_REASON` and that gets passed into the lambda function and if it equals `REASON_PLACED` it does something with Count but not sure what.

#4. Groups by `CD_STATUS` value.

Comment: Would be better if you can attach the schema for Student table and other relevant related tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from stat in XpoSession.Query<STUDENT>()
where stat.ID_PERSON.DT_BIRTH >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20)
&& stat.Status.Where(val => val.CD_REASON == Constants.REASON_PLACED).Count() == 0
select stat.CD_STATUS.Trim()).ToList().GroupBy(val => val);
```

Looks like it's getting whatever the `CD_STATUS` value is for students who are more than 20 years old where their status isn't whatever `Constants.REASON_PLACED` value is and grouping them by the `CD_STATUS` value.

Without more context or additional code, it's not really possible to provide a better answer here.